# List and findAll

Tags: java, sql, list, grails

So I have a method that traverses through my users and finds where there ids are the same. It then adds those users to an array. I have it so it will find all the users with the same IDs. Not I need to refine the search to where the Ids are the same AND the accounts are valid. (if the accounts are anything else (deactivated, cancelled, time-out,ext) then its no problem so I dont need to search for them.

This is what works

```
    static List<Users> getAllWithDuplicateIDs() {
    findAll('from User where id in (select id from User group by id having count(*) > 1)', [])
}
```

this is what I'm trying.

```
findAll('FROM User WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM User group by id having count(*) > 1) AND accountStatus = 'valid' ', [])
```

error Im getting:

User.groovy: 32: unexpected token: valid @ line 32, column 122.
   (*) > 1) AND accountStatus = 'valid' ', 
                                 ^

Any help/opinions is/are greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: What is the exception? Use escape characters for 'valid' as `\'valid\'` as well.

Comment: findAll("FROM User WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM User group by id having count(*) > 1) AND accountStatus = 'valid' ", [])

Comment: The exception is complaining about "valid" because you query string ends earlier than you thought. Use escape character, i.e. `\'valid\'` to see if it works.

Comment: Try this: `findAll('FROM User WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM User group by id having count(*) > 1) AND accountStatus = :status', [status: 'valid'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your single quotes with double quotes, otherwise escape the single quotes. leave 'valid' how it is if replacing the singles with doubles. Yeclipse shows how